# How to use categories, sub-categories and customize navigation view

Tags: categories

1. On navigation, can a parent-grandchild menu appear? That is, are we able to pick and choose which categories we would like to suppress?

Example: if taxonomy shows:
  Food>Fruit>Citrus>Oranges>Types of oranges
Can we design the navigation to show:
  Fruit>Oranges>Types of oranges

2. How many subcategories are possible?
3. On navigation, can we rename categories on the front-end but keep a different taxonomy on the back end?

Example: if taxonomy is:
Food>Fruit>Citrus>Oranges>Types of oranges
Can we actually have the users see these words instead (but they should experience navigation per the taxonomy?)
  Yummy things>Fruitilicious>Citrus

Answer (score 0):

- that would be CSS only, you could add a filter to hide the ones you dont want but its the same, you will hand pick them
- all the ones you will want
- you can change the `Name` and keep the `slug` but the slug will be seen in the URL

**Other Options:**

- You can actually either search for a plugin or create one to have a second `value` (lets call it `front-end-name`) for the categories or create a new entire new type of category system like a new .
- you could use the Description field to have a second value for the name and actually pull that as the name in the front-end, you will need a filter still.

Answer (score 0):

As what I have researched from google is, they prefer you to keep it simple and easy for your target audience to navigate your site.

Make it as easy as even a 7 year old child can navigate your site.